# Why load event on images isn't working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, load, requirejs

I'm trying to add a `load` event on my images with native javascript. Here is the code :

```
var imgs = $("figure img"); // querySelectorAll

for(var i = 0, l = imgs.length ; i < l ; ++i)
  imgs[i].addEventListener("load", img_loaded, false);
```

But my function `img_loaded` is never called. `imgs.length` is 3, and I'm sure the event is attached.

Any idea ? I have the same problem with window, `window.addEventListener("load", window_loaded, false)` sometimes works.

I'm using `requirejs` and it is a `nodejs server`. Testing on both Chrome and Firefox.

---

(Note: The `$` isn't related to jQuery, it's just an alias for `document.querySelectorAll`.)

Comment: You appear to be using jQuery, why use `addEventListener`?

Comment: Sorry `$` is a shorcut for querySelectorAll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely reason is that the `load` event has already fired. With an `img`, you can check whether its `load` event has been fired by checking its `complete` property.

This will reliably call `img_loaded` for the related images, for instance:

```
var imgs = $("figure img");
var img;

for(var i = 0, l = imgs.length ; i < l ; ++i) {
  img = imgs[i];
  img.addEventListener("load", img_loaded, false);
  if (img.complete) {
    img_loaded.call(img);
    img.removeEventListener("load", img_loaded, false);
  }
}
```

You may be wondering why, in the above, first I attach the event handler, then I check whether `img.complete` is checked, and if so I remove the event handler and call it. That's to prevent missed called. There's only one main JavaScript thread, but the *browser* is not single-threaded. If we checked `complete` first, then added the handler on the next line, it would be perfectly valid for the browser, between those two lines, to see that it has finished loading the image, look for handlers for the `load` event, not see any, and set `complete` — and we wouldn't get a callback at all. It's *really unlikely*, but it can happen.

For the same reason, the above may call `img_loaded` *twice* in very rare situations for the same image. So you want to handle the possibility it's already been called, in the function.

Comment: Thanks ! Very complete answer, it's working now. And how I can check if window is complete ?

Comment: @thomash: I'm not aware of a way, if you don't know for sure your code will run before it has happened. But do you really need `window` `load`? What's the use case?

Comment: No I don't really need it. I encountered the problem but I've solved it. I just wonder how I can check it.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think you can. I don't see anything on the [MDN page for `window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window), for instance.